# NUXT: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I'm starting out with vue and nuxt, I have a project using vuetify and I'm trying to modify the carousel component to dynamically load images from the static folder. So far I've come up with:

```
    <template>
    <v-carousel>
        <v-carousel-item v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i" :src="item.src"></v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
    </template>


    <script>
    function getImagePaths() {
        var glob = require("glob");
        var options = {
        cwd: "./static"
        };
        var fileNames = glob.sync("*", options);
        var items = [];
        fileNames.forEach(fileName =>
        items.push({
            'src': '/'+fileName
        })
        );
        return items;
    }
    export default {
        data() {
        return {items :getImagePaths()};
        }
    };

    </script>
```

When I test this I see:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '....\node_modules\fs.realpath'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in ....\node_modules\fs.realpath'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '....\node_modules\glob'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/sync.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '.....\node_modules\glob'
```

googling this I see a bunch of references like https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447.

These suggest that you have to midify the webpack config file with something like:

```
node: {
  fs: 'empty'
}
```

I know very little about webpack. I found https://nuxtjs.org/faq/extend-webpack/ , but am not sure how to modify the webpack config file in this case.

How do I do this?

Comment: you cant use fs module on client

Comment: Ok, What would you suggest.

Comment: make an api endpoint that would return image urls for the images and make api call to get it in asyncData

Comment: Does this require the axios module?

Comment: not necessary, but yes

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use NodeJs specific module on browser.

To solve your issue, you can create an API using Nuxt server middleware. The code below, inspired by https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template.

1. Create a file, `index.js` in `api/index.js`. Then fill it with:

   ```
   const express = require('express')

   // Create express instance
   const app = express()

   // Require API routes
   const carousel = require('./routes/carousel')

   // Import API Routes
   app.use(carousel)

   // Export the server middleware
   module.exports = {
     path: '/api',
     handler: app
   }
   ```
2. Create `carousel.js` in `api/routes/carousel.js`. Then fill it with:

   ```
   const { Router } = require('express')
   const glob = require('glob')

   const router = Router()

   router.get('/carousel/images', async function (req, res) {
     const options = {
       cwd: './static'
     }
     const filenames = glob.sync('*', options)

     let items = [];
     filenames.forEach(filename =>
       items.push({
         'src': '/'+filename
       })
     );

     return res.json({ data: items })
   })

   module.exports = router
   ```
3. Register your server middleware in `nuxt.config.js`

   ```
   module.exports = {
     build: {
       ...
     },
     serverMiddleware: [
       '~/api/index.js'
     ]
   }
   ```
4. Call the api in your page / component. I assume you're using Axios here ([axios-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module)).

   ```
   <script>
   export default {
     async asyncData ({ $axios }) {
       const images = (await $axios.$get('/api/carousel/images')).data

       return { images }
     }
   }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed exemplary code. Based on this code and the express-template, I managed to load image from specific directory in a dynamic page based on the route name. However, I found that such custom API won't work for static generated site using `nuxt generate`. If I understand correctly, this is because there simply won't be any server we can call our API from. I am wondering is there any workaround for this? Is it possible to use custom API like shown here for static site?

Comment: you're a genius

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but it may be helpful for someone to disable  fs in their browser.
Like this:

nuxt.config.js

```
  build: {
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {

       config.node= {
          fs: 'empty'
        }

       // ....
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your `nuxt-config.js`:

```
build: { extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
  config.node = {
    fs: 'empty'
  }

  // ....
}},
```